# Can I restrict an Azure service principal to manipulate only a specific group? (microsoft graph)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I just created a service principal in Azure AD with its token. Then I created a Group and gave Owner permission on this group to the service principal I just created. Also added some users to it.
Then, using login.microsoftonline.com I was able to authenticate my SPN.
With it's token, I tried to list the user for this group and failed.

Here is where I got confused:

I went to the API permissions and added the Users.Read.All to the service principal. The problem now is that, using microsoft graph, I can read all AD users metadata.

There's any way to restrict all the API calls from this service principal to only this group where it is Owner?
Or maybe an alternative to that? Where instead of using graph I use another solution. I'm open to alternatives.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a way to lockdown mailbox access using "new-csapplicationaccesspolicy" or "new-applicationaccesspolicy"

This works by specifying the Azure AppId, and the UPN (user or group) which locks down which mailboxes can be accessed via the graph API app.

However, this is for the mail.read.all scope, and i'm not sure if there is anything for the user.read.all scope, but its worth looking into.

Hope that helps.

Reference: [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps) (learn.microsoft.com)